# How to evaluate the result of Share.RequestAsync in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

Iam using [Xamarin Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android) to share a URI. Is there anyway to evaluate the result if it was shared or cancelled. From the share dialog the user either share or cancel sharing.

```
public async Task ShareUri(string uri)
    {
        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Uri = uri,
                Title = "Share Web Link"
            });
    }
```

Comment: No.  The method does not return any status value.

Comment: Any custom renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this as that function just returns a void.

If you look at native development too, there's no way to get that information on either platform due to privacy reasons (unless the device is jailbroken)